# Поиск файла из ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть `ListBox` в который добавляются файлы через `OpenFileDialog`. Как по нажатию на `Button` найти информацию в интернете о выбранной строке в `ListBox`? То есть пользователь выделят строку, нажимает Button и открывается стандартный браузер, где в поиске Google отображается выделенная ранее строка.

Answer (score 2):

В обработчике клика кнопки берете [`ListBox.SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) и после вытягивания строки отправляете ее в [`Process.Start()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public void OpenSearch(string value)
{
    var uri = new Uri($"https://www.google.by/search?q={value}");
    Process.Start(uri.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать фреим Selenium Web Driver. Для этого по приведенной в конце ссылке скачайте dll под язык C# и драйвер браузера  (если стандартный то IEDriverServer.exe) Подключите WebDriver.dll в свой проект, добавьте пространство имен и  следующий :

```
 using OpenQA.Selenium;

//****

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string get = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        var options = new OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerOptions
        {
            IgnoreZoomLevel = true
        };

        var Browser = new OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver(@"pathToDriver",options); // Путь к файлу IEDriverServer.exe
        Browser.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        Browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.ru");
        IWebElement textbox = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib"));
        textbox.SendKeys(get + OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
    }
```

Страничка откуда можно скачать dll и драйвер браузера http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/